# Knex NodeJS and inserting into the database

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am new to nodejs and was trying to set up an API server, here is my first attempt. I wanted to use mysql instead of mongo db.

My problem is that 'knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email});' doesn't seem to want to save to the database.

```
var dbConfig = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'db_nodeapi'
  }
};
var express = require('express');                       // call express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');                // call body-parser
var knex = require('knex')(dbConfig);                   // set up database connection
var app = express();                                    // define our app using express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));     // configure app to use bodyParser() 
app.use(bodyParser.json());                             // this will let us get the data from a POST
var router     = express.Router();                      // get an instance of the express Router
router.use(function(req, res, next) {                   // middle ware for authentication
    console.log(' -Logging- ');
    next();                                             // continue to next route without stopping
});
router.get('/', function(req, res) {                    // listen for a post on root
    res.json({ message: ' -Success- ' });   
});
router.route('/user')                                   // set up user route
    .post(function(req, res) {                          // listen for a post on user
        console.log(' -Post -');                        // report a post
        knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email});   // insert user into user table
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok' });     // respond back to request
    });
app.use('/api', router);                                // register routes beginning with /api  
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                    // set server port number
app.listen(port);                                       // setup listener
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // report port number chosen
```

Problem is I can't get knex to add to the database!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Here is the database

Comment: 1) are you sure an email is getting posted? What happens if you change the line console.log(' -Post -') to console.log(' - Post - ' + req.body.email) ? 
2) Are you sure that's the syntax for insert? It doesn't look like the current documentation, which uses something more like knex.insert(info).into('user')

Comment: req.body.email is set to the posted value of email, I have checked. body-parser takes care of this I am led to believe.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Now what about knex? Are you sure that query syntax works? For example, if you remove the code from the route and add a quick line after you require knex (something like): knex('user').insert({email:'AQuickTest@Example.com'}); what happens? And then what happens if you add a second line like knex.insert({email: 'AnotherTest@example.com}).into('user') does that work?

Comment: knex.insert({email: req.body.email}).into('user'); tried nothing, not even an error. Also tried knex('user').insert({email:'AQuickTest@Example.com'}); after var knex = ... line. nothing. Tried knex.insert({email: 'AnotherTest@example.com}).into('user') ... nothing. Tried both ... nothing.

Comment: Hmm. It could be that knex is not connecting to the database at all, or it could be that it's failing silently. id is specified as not null - is it tied to a sequence or an auto-increment or something? Or is it possible thats a point of failure? BTW - you can add 'debug: true, ' to your dbConfig to have the SQL syntax and parameter bindings output to the console. That would be helpful as well.

Comment: I removed the id completely, thought that would help ... debug: true will try. Code too long to post.

Comment: Tried setting up a user account for the table just in case the password can't be blank. - nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72520/discussion-between-stephen-brown-and-gojirademonstah).

Answer (score 37):

The problem in your code is that you are missing the ".then" statement, which causes the actual execution of the code.

```
   knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email})
      .then( function (result) {
          res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok' });     // respond back to request
       })
```

That should work. Since knex.js's insert function is a promise, you need to call .then() to actually call it.

Comment: Does knex use some kind of lazy promises? The insert *should* be executed regardless of whether or not the result is handled (assuming `insert` returns a regular promise).

Comment: Yes. Knex needs a .then() for it to execute.

Comment: what if I want to add more than just and email, or multiple objects?

Comment: I'm no longer using knex, but I believe they have a mass insert function that you can use. You can check on their documention on batch insert: https://knexjs.org/#Utility-BatchInsert

Comment: doesn't work with await either.. they should instead do something like knex(...).insert(...).execute() which retrieves and executes a promise, thus working with await AND one can add .then if wanted

Comment: Or an `await` will get it to run

Answer (score 12):

Someone has already given a solution. I am here to talk about why adding a **then** statement can solve this problem.

In fact, **then**, **catch** statement are both ok. Please refer to the knex documentation(http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-then), which mentions:

> Coerces the current query builder chain into a promise state.

So **select**, **update**, **insert**, etc. are just the query statement builder, you have to use **then** or **catch** to convert it to promise state.

Examples are as follows:

```
knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}) //not working
knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}).then(()=>{}) //working
knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}).catch(()=>{}) //working

.then(()=>{
    knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}) //not working
    knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}).then(()=>{}) //working
    knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}).catch(()=>{}) //working
    return knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}) //working
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved try this I think there should be some after hook in knex where we can do this automatically but till then this should works.

```
 knex('users')
      .insert(data)
      .then(async () => {
        const result = await knex.raw('select LAST_INSERT_ID() as id');
        const id = result[0][0].id;
        const user = await knex.from('users').where('id', id);
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok', user: user[0] });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue once, try this:

```
//...
router.route('/user').post(function(req, res) {                          
  knex('user').insert({email: req.body.email}).then(function(ret){
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok'/*,ret:ret*/});  
  });   
});
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was seen the above solutions all are good if you want to add more than one field without mentioning each field you can go with the below syntax:

```
knex('students').insert(req.body).then((newUser) => {
  res.json({newUser});
}).catch((e)=>console.log(e));
```

**So here your input tag names should be equivalent to the database table field names**